# script for Blogger page redirect with masking?

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, blogger

I need script to redirect blogger page to another website with masking(showing my website url instead)

I can successfully redirect already but can't mask.
To redirect I use these:

window.location = "https://testurl";

OR
https://testurl/' />

What do I add to mask?

Comment: ***I can successfully redirect already but can't mask. To redirect I use these:
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=https://testurl/' />
OR
<script>
 
window.location = "https://testurl";
 
</script>

Comment: You can’t change browser url bar, but you can embeed another website in iframe on your site.

Comment: Then how do I embed another website in iframe on my site?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: just putting iframe code in html of the page doesnt help. I need external website to fully replace the page while having my url

Comment: I need it to work like framed subdomain redirect